# Postgres синтаксическая ошибка

Tags: postgresql

Собственно запрос

```
Select t_id,end_data, 
case when tbl_city.NAZV is null then tc_name else tc_name || ', ' || NAZV end || ', ' || address as NAZV, 
case status when 0 then 'Не подтверждена' when 1 then 'Подтверждена' when 2 then 'В работе' when 3 then 'На проверке' else 'Закрыта' end as st,
case when cell_ticket is null then 'Не назначено' else cell_ticket end as st,
case when cell_ticket is null then 'Не указано' else cell_ticket end as cell
from us_ticket.ticket
join us_ticket.tbl_countryside on ticket.city_id = tbl_countryside.tc_id
left join us_ticket.tbl_city on tbl_countryside.citycode = tbl_city.city_id;
```

Ошибка на строке

```
case when cell_ticket is null then 'Не указано' else cell_ticket end as cell
```

Как только ее убираю все начинает работать. Ругается на эту часть `then "Не указано"`

Текст ошибки

> ОШИБКА:  неверное значение для целого числа: "Не указано"
>      СТРОКА 1: ...та' end as st, case when cell_ticket is null then 'Не указан...

Comment: Процитируйте текст ошибки в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил описание ошибки

Comment: А не должно ли там быть `case when status = 0 then` ?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю синтаксис не обязательно так делать. Но я подобное делал, ошибка не ушла.

Comment: А вы подобное во всех `when` делали, не только в первом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то все результаты выражения [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-conditional.html) должны приводиться к одному типу. Полный алгоритм выбора к какому типу приводить результат описан в [документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/typeconv-union-case.html).

Решение — явно привести результат `cell_ticket` к `text`:

```
CASE WHEN cell_ticket IS NULL THEN 'Не указано' ELSE cell_ticket::text END
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое что бросается в глаза это: 
`"Не указано"` -> `'Не указано'`

Comment: Да тоже обратил внимание, что ковычки меняет.. Причем, если заместо строки подставить число - все отрабатывает нормально

Comment: Число является валидным литералом чего не скажешь о строке вида "text" ;)

Comment: Ну в других же случаях все строки выводятся как надо.

Comment: Синтаксис psql строки понимает только в одинарных кавычках

Comment: В запросе я использую одинарные ковычки.О-о. Просто он мне в ошибках пишет двойные почему-то

Comment: Потому что кодировка не та, удалите кавычки в запросе и заново напечатайте. Видать толи скопипастили откуда-то то ли раскладка клавиатуры была иная

Comment: Не помогает. Если пишу строку типа '123', то нормально, текст - ошибка.

Comment: Не верю) Синтаксису все-равно что  '123' что  'текст'

Comment: В ошибках двойные кавычки потому что они так в сообщениях об ошибках и указаны в исходниках: `msgstr "неверное значение для целого числа: \"%s\""`, независимо от источника данных. А синтаксически для запроса - двойные кавычки указывают на имя объекта (таблицы, столбца), одинарные - некий строковой литерал неизвестного типа. И вот потому что тип неизвестен, '123' можно привести к целому числу. А 'текст' - нельзя и потому ошибка.